# Getting error message when returning a boolean in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have this function:

```
func isDrawRadiusEnough(let point: CGPoint) -> Bool {
    let distance = sqrtf(powf(point.x-lastPointDrawn.x, 2)+powf(point.y-lastPointDrawn.y, 2))

    return distance > drawRadius // Error: Could not find an overload for '>' that accepts the supplied arguments
}
```

`drawRadius` is an `Int` and is a property in the same class as the function. `lastPointDrawn` is a `CGPoint` and is also a property.

When I set the `drawRadius` as a Float the error disappears, but I don't want it to be a float. In Obj-C this was valid but it is not in Swift. Anyone know a workaround?

Comment: try `let distance : Double = {etc...}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sqrtf` returns a Float value.

Since `drawRadius` is an `Int`, you need to convert it to a `Float` prior to performing the compare operation.

Try `return distance > Float(drawRadius)`

This is due to Swift's implementation of type safety. No implicit type conversions are performed.

Comment: And how do you convert in Swift? In all the other C-like languages you put (Type) before the variable.

Comment: Thanks now I know how to convert in Swift :D

Comment: Glad to have helped. Also, please remember to accept/upvote this answer if you believed it solved your problem. You should also do the same for any answers you received in the past that solved your problem on previous questions. This rewards the answerer, gives you a little reputation bump and helps other members in the community identify a good answer.